# SUM and groupBy in solr

Tags: solr, lucene

How to execute this query:

select SUM(Primary_cause_vaR),
RiskType,market from bil_tos Where skuType='Product' group by RiskType,market;
I've used http://wiki.apache.org/solr/StatsComponent for this:

- I see only sum with respective groupBy fields but i want to see RiskType,
  market fields also in the result

Answer (score 0):

StatsComponent supports only GROUP BY (stats.facet) on a single field at a time. Using multiple stats.facet parameters has the effect of multiple GROUP BY clauses, if SQL allowed such a thing. What you can do is facet on RiskType, and then for each facet value do another query adding `fq=RiskType:<value>` and facet on market. It will take a bunch of queries but eventually you'll have the entire result.

Answer (score 0):

Using [stats](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Stats+Component) feature particularly stats.facet:

```
select?q=*:*&fq=fldA:O&rows=0&wt=xml&indent=true&stats=true&stats.field=Amount&stats.facet=fldB
```